# kubectl run nginx ,minikube Ubuntu apiserver 18.04 issue

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, kubectl, minikube

Errors while setting up CI/CD environment in Ubuntu 18.04 in Parallel Desktop environment:
There is an issue connecting with proxy and running nginx image.
I am trying to setup kubernetes CI CD environment on Ubuntu, but I am getting few errors related to apiserver proxy and `kubectl get pods` command is failing with `unable to connect` message.

```
$sudo minikube start --memory 8000 --cpus 2 --kubernetes-version v1.11.10 --vm-driver none

Wait failed: waiting for k8s-app=kube-proxy: timed out waiting for the condition


$kubectl run nginx --image nginx --port 80

error: failed to discover supported resources: Get https://192.168.64.19:8443/apis/apps/v1?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Below are docker, kubectl & minikube version  version used:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:18:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.5.0
commit: d1151d93385a70c5a03775e166e94067791fe2d9
```

Content of ~/.kube/config content

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/parallels/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.64.19:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/parallels/.minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /home/parallels/.minikube/client.key
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of kubernetes in minikube? does it work without specifying the version?

Comment: Can you post output of `minikube status` and check the `~/.minikube/logs`. You could also try running the minikube in verbos mode `minikube start -v=7`

Comment: $ minikube status

host: 
kubelet: 
apiserver: 
kubeconfig:                                                                                                                                  
    
                                                                                                                   
    
                                                                                                                    
And i was providing kubernetes version on command line as minikube start --memory 8000 --cpus 2 --kubernetes-version v1.11.10

Comment: Beware of [Kubectl Version Skew Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/version-skew-policy/#kubectl). Using `kubectl` version `v1.16.x` with `kube-apiserver` version `v1.11.x` is not supported.

Comment: My Current docker version is 18.06.0-ce and minkube version is minikube version: v0.28.2  kubectl version version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16 .. } Kubeadm version is Major:"1", Minor:"11" and now i am able to run kubectl cluster create commands . and minkube status is running . I was getting error because of swapoff was not enabled ,but couldn't understand how it works because swapoff -a command failed with can't allocate memory .